# Pandas: Converting excel column to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, conditional-statements

I'm converting my excel to python, below are the rows in excel

Symbol (Column B): Column has different symbols

Date (Column C): Column has date with time

Price   (Column D): Column has price

Lower Low (Column E): Column has mention "Lower Low" or empty cells

Lower Values (Column F): Column has this formula in F2 cell -

"IF(B2<>B1,D2,IF(E2="Lower Low",D2,F1))"

I'm trying to convert the formula in F2 using pandan Dataframe and apply this to a group as per Symbol column:

created mod_df DataFrame for the above mentioned  columns:

mod_df['Lower_Value'] = np.where(mod_df['Symbol'] != mod_df['Symbol'].shift(1),mod_df['Price']
,np.where(mod_df['Lower Low'] == 'Lower Low', mod_df['Price'], mod_df['Lower_Value'].shift(1)))

I get this error: KeyError: 'Lower_Value', could anyone suggest how to fix this.

```
data= {'Symbol': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
        'Date': ['2023-05-12 16:00:00', '2023-05-15 15:00:00', '2023-05-15 22:00:00', '2023-05-16 07:00:00',
                 '2023-05-16 14:00:00', '2023-05-17 07:00:00', '2023-05-17 20:00:00', '2023-05-18 02:00:00'],
        'Price': [0.89845,0.90065,0.90042,0.89841,0.89462,0.89437,0.89455,0.89248],
        'Lower Low': ['', '', '', '', '', 'Lower Low', '', ''],
        'Lower Value': [0.89845, 0.89845, 0.89845, 0.89845, 0.89845, 0.89437, 0.89437, 0.89437],

        }

mod_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(mod_df)

Dataframe:
**********
Symbol          Date        Price    Lower Low  
A   12-05-2023 16:00:00    0.89845          
A   15-05-2023 15:00:00    0.90065          
A   15-05-2023 22:00:00    0.90042          
A   16-05-2023 07:00:00    0.89841          
A   16-05-2023 14:00:00    0.89462          
A   17-05-2023 07:00:00    0.89437   Lower Low  
A   17-05-2023 20:00:00    0.89455          
A   18-05-2023 02:00:00    0.89248  

Required Output:
****************
Symbol          Date        Price   Lower Low   Lower Value
A   12-05-2023 16:00:00     0.89845             0.89845
A   15-05-2023 15:00:00     0.90065             0.89845
A   15-05-2023 22:00:00     0.90042             0.89845
A   16-05-2023 07:00:00     0.89841             0.89845
A   16-05-2023 14:00:00     0.89462             0.89845
A   17-05-2023 07:00:00     0.89437 Lower Low   0.89437
A   17-05-2023 20:00:00     0.89455             0.89437
A   18-05-2023 02:00:00     0.89248             0.89437
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've created your `mod_df` DataFrame from your excel file exactly as you've written in your question, you simply don't have a key called `Lower_Value`. Change it to `Lower_Values`and it should key correctly

**EDITED:**
Here is an updated example that matches your required output given your example data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data= {'Symbol': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
        'Date': ['2023-05-12 16:00:00', '2023-05-15 15:00:00', '2023-05-15 22:00:00', '2023-05-16 07:00:00',
                 '2023-05-16 14:00:00', '2023-05-17 07:00:00', '2023-05-17 20:00:00', '2023-05-18 02:00:00'],
        'Price': [0.89845,0.90065,0.90042,0.89841,0.89462,0.89437,0.89455,0.89248],
        'Lower Low': ['', '', '', '', '', 'Lower Low', '', ''],
        'Lower Value': [0.89845, 0.89845, 0.89845, 0.89845, 0.89845, 0.89437, 0.89437, 0.89437],

        }

mod_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
mod_df.pop('Lower Value')

## This is your starting DataFrame without the "Lower Value" column
print("STARTING DF\n", mod_df)

## Instantiate the "Lower_Value" column
mod_df["Lower Value"] = np.nan
print("\nNOW HAS NEW COLUMN\n", mod_df)

## Now use your logic to populate the "Lower Value" column
mod_df['Lower Value'] = np.where(mod_df['Symbol'] != mod_df['Symbol'].shift(1),
                                 mod_df['Price'],
                                 np.where(mod_df['Lower Low'] == 'Lower Low', 
                                          mod_df['Price'], 
                                          mod_df['Lower Value'].shift(1)))

## Current logic doesn't fill in the entire column, use this to forward-fill the values
mod_df = mod_df.fillna(method='ffill')
print("\nTARGET OUTPUT\n", mod_df)
```

Produces:

```
STARTING DF
   Symbol                 Date    Price  Lower Low
0      A  2023-05-12 16:00:00  0.89845           
1      A  2023-05-15 15:00:00  0.90065           
2      A  2023-05-15 22:00:00  0.90042           
3      A  2023-05-16 07:00:00  0.89841           
4      A  2023-05-16 14:00:00  0.89462           
5      A  2023-05-17 07:00:00  0.89437  Lower Low
6      A  2023-05-17 20:00:00  0.89455           
7      A  2023-05-18 02:00:00  0.89248           

NOW HAS NEW COLUMN
   Symbol                 Date    Price  Lower Low  Lower Value
0      A  2023-05-12 16:00:00  0.89845                     NaN
1      A  2023-05-15 15:00:00  0.90065                     NaN
2      A  2023-05-15 22:00:00  0.90042                     NaN
3      A  2023-05-16 07:00:00  0.89841                     NaN
4      A  2023-05-16 14:00:00  0.89462                     NaN
5      A  2023-05-17 07:00:00  0.89437  Lower Low          NaN
6      A  2023-05-17 20:00:00  0.89455                     NaN
7      A  2023-05-18 02:00:00  0.89248                     NaN

TARGET OUTPUT
   Symbol                 Date    Price  Lower Low  Lower Value
0      A  2023-05-12 16:00:00  0.89845                 0.89845
1      A  2023-05-15 15:00:00  0.90065                 0.89845
2      A  2023-05-15 22:00:00  0.90042                 0.89845
3      A  2023-05-16 07:00:00  0.89841                 0.89845
4      A  2023-05-16 14:00:00  0.89462                 0.89845
5      A  2023-05-17 07:00:00  0.89437  Lower Low      0.89437
6      A  2023-05-17 20:00:00  0.89455                 0.89437
7      A  2023-05-18 02:00:00  0.89248                 0.89437
```

Comment: In excel the column name is "Lower Values " in pandas I have created a dataframe "mod_df" and mod_df['Lower_Value'] is created for applying the same formula & I get this error.

Comment: The error message is clear in that you are trying to use a key that doesn't exist. Have you instantiated the `Lower_Value` column, or are you trying to create it using this formula? If it's the latter, then the key error is coming from `mod_df['Lower_Value'].shift(1)` since that column doesn't exist yet

Comment: I am trying to create "mod_df['Lower_Value']", using this formula since that is how I did in excel. "Lower Values" (Column F) F2 cell - "IF(B2<>B1,D2,IF(E2="Lower Low",D2,F1))". Could you suggest how to do in pandas.

Comment: If you post some example data as well as your full current code for creating your `mod_df`, that will increase the odds someone will be able to help you

Comment: Thanks, I have created a dataframe.

Comment: For whoever down voted this answer - it would be considerate to explain why you down voted a functioning solution

Comment: This wasn't a functioning solution until you posted the edit, and the section above the edit is incorrect and should be deleted IMO.

Comment: Given the information in the original post, a typo in the key was the likeliest solution. If someone thought this was incorrect, perhaps they should have offered an alternative solution

Comment: Thanks, this solution gave me the required output.

Comment: could you suggest how to apply mod_df['Lower Value'] column to groupby based on Symbol column

Comment: Perhaps that's worth posting a new question? There are plenty of Pandas experts who could help you with that very quickly